# MiDaS model quantization on coral edge TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, quantization, edge-tpu, pycoral

I am having issues with the fully integer quantized MiDaS model. The aim is to run it on coral edge tpu, however the results are inaccurate.

I tried to convert the model using [OpenVINO mo.py script and the openvino2tensorflow toll](https://qiita.com/PINTO/items/ed06e03eb5c007c2e102). The results are inaccurate compared with the float32 model.
I provided an image of the model's full_integer_quant.tflite output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S347.png).